# QtRemoteObjects SSL transport

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, qt5, remoteobject

Is there good example of how to implement custom protocol for *QtRemoteObjects*?

[There are](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtremoteobjects-module.html) not too well documented classes `QtROClientFactory` and `QtROServerFactory` in documentation (because in 5.9 *QtRO* just technology preview). There is no example of how to implement custom transport into examples of `qtremoteobjects/`.

I especially interested in implementation of custom scheme `ssl://` via `QSslSocket`.

Comment: You could try to "copy" the tcp implementation and replace all tcp sockets by ssl sockets etc. Have a look at https://github.com/qt/qtremoteobjects/blob/5.9/src/remoteobjects/qconnection_tcpip_backend_p.h and https://github.com/qt/qtremoteobjects/blob/5.9/src/remoteobjects/qconnection_tcpip_backend.cpp

Comment: @Felix It seems `QtSsl` not support client auth from server side. It is very bad omission.

Comment: Define "client auth". You can use client-certificates, if that's what you mean. If you want "real" user authentication (like http auth), you could use a 2-step implementation. Authenticate via HTTP to get a token, and send that token on connection the ssl socket (or use QtWebSockets and pass it as header)